# java - Sprite won't stop moving (Libgdx)

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite

I can't stop a sprite from moving.

Here's my code:

```
boolean moving;

Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new Input(){
       public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            projected = new Vector3(screenX, screenY,0);
            cam.unproject(projected);

            if(position.x != projected.x || position.y != projected.y){
                pathX = projected.x - position.x;
                pathY = projected.y - position.y;

                distance = (float) Math.sqrt(pathX * pathX + pathY * pathY);
                directionX = pathX / distance;
                directionY = pathY / distance;

                moving= true;
            }
            if(projected.x == position.x || projected.y == position.y){
                moving = false;
            }
            return true;

}

public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   

        if(moving){
            System.out.println(moving);

            position.x += directionX * Speed * delta;
            position.y += directionY * Speed * delta;
        }
```

The problem that moving is always true, and the sprite won't stop no matter what.

Comment: The only place your code ever sets moving to false is when someone taps down on the screen on the exact pixel the object was already in, and even then only if the transformation math works out exactly the same. Both are nearly impossible conditions, so never are they both going to be satisfied.

Comment: As @Tenfour04 mentioned this `if` statement will never be met. Instead you should only set the right direction in the `tocuhDown` and update the position in the update method. There you should stop your character, if it is near to the touch point and maybe correct his position to be exactly the touch point.